# How to create this event filter in AWS SQS

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, eventfilter, aws-sqs-fifo

This is the real data structure of my current json data, it contains `[]` in the data in the first place.

```
{"events":[{"type":"message","message":{"type":"text"}}]}
```

So, basically I just want text message type data from SQS, but now I don't know what should the filter be.

Comment: can you tell me on which field you want to add filter condition?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using yaml in serverless, I´d try this:

```
filterPatterns:
    - body: {events: {type: ["message"], message: {type: ["text"]}}}
```

In case it helps, I had a similar scenario: in my case, I want a function to be triggered only when inside the body of the SQS message, the field "type" has values "create" or "delete"}

In my case, the next code worked:

```
filterPatterns:
    - body : {type: [create, delete]}
```

Comment: The second example worked very nicely for me after having tried many variants. Using AWS  SDK 3, `SendMessageCommand`.

`const body = { type : 'create' }`